# Using regex to split text into columns using

Tags: python, regex, split

I have several files with measurement date and time as shown as one text.

```
Measurement date: 22.06.06 14:03:49
Measurement date: 22.06.07 14:28:30
Measurement date: 22.06.09 07:42:38
Measurement date: 22.06.10 08:38:56
                 .
                 .
                 .
```

I want to split like below using regex

```
 date                              time
22.06.06                      14:03:49
22.06.07                      14:28:30
22.06.09                      07:42:38
22.06.10                      08:38:56
```

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: `"\t".join("Measurement date: 22.06.06 14:03:49".split()[2:])`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["date"] = df["text"].str.extract(r'\b(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\b')
df["time"] = df["text"].str.extract(r'\b(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\b')
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried str.extract.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regex (absolutely nothing wrong with regex, I just like to make things more simple for the future me), this example below uses only `split`:

```
fulltext = """Measurement date: 22.06.06 14:03:49
Measurement date: 22.06.07 14:28:30
Measurement date: 22.06.09 07:42:38
Measurement date: 22.06.10 08:38:56"""

print("Date \t\t Time")
for line in fulltext.split('\n'):
    print(f"{line.split()[2]}\t {line.split()[3]}")
```

Comment: I see your point. I give your suggestion a try.